# You’ve become honorary Bidens

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does "You’ve become honorary Bidens" mean "You've become honorary members of the Biden family"?

> Kamala, Doug — like it or not — you’re family. **You’ve become honorary Bidens** and there’s no way out.

> Source: [A PRESIDENCY FOR ALL AMERICANS](https://joebiden.com/presidency-for-all-americans/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct. "The Johnsons" means the Johnson family. And "You've become honorary Bidens" means "You've become honorary members of the Biden family" as you suggest.